# Docker for windows missing quick start terminal

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I installed the latest version of Docker for windows in my windows 10 machine. It seems the new Docker Desktop toolbox doesn't contain the Quick start terminal. Every documentation says to check the quick start terminal option at the time of installation. I dont see any option to check that option with the latest Docker toolbox.
Is there any way we could install Quick start terminal for windows.
Or are there any other alternate to the QS terminal. My objective is to build, tag and push / pull docker images to a gitlab registry. Powershell, command promt doesn't work because its a windows machine.

Comment: what docker for desktop version are you using?

Comment: Also posted on https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-for-windows-missing-quick-start-terminal/117731

Comment: @NoamYizraeli I am using the latest version Docker Desktop 4.2.0

Answer (score 1):

with the new `Docker-for-desktop` versions there's no need for the added toolbox as marked [here](https://jff--docker-docs.netlify.app/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/)

> Legacy desktop solution. Docker Toolbox is for older Mac and Windows
> systems that do not meet the requirements of Docker for Mac and
> Docker for Windows. We recommend updating to the newer applications,
> if possible.

You can just open any typical terminal in your OS of choice and use the `docker cli` if you can't remember the exact usage try `docker --help`